# how to conditionally replace prefix or prefix/suffix gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

I have 2 cases of strings I need to gsub:

prefix is always the same: ex `xxx`
middle could be `hhh` or `yyy`

```
'xxx-hhh-111'
'xxx-yyy-aaa'
```

What I need to do in both cases is always remove the prefix: `xxx` so this works fine:

```
'xxx-yyy-aaa'.gsub('xxx', '')
```

outcome:

```
'-yyy-aaa'
```

but sometimes I need to check whether the body is `hhh` and if true, then remove the prefix and the suffix (the pattern is that the suffix will be random digits)

I guess I can accomplish this with regex, any thoughts?

so the outcome I am looking for when the string is `xxx-hhh-111` is:

```
'hhh'
```

The easy way would be 2 statements, one for the first always removing the xxx which I am using above

and one just checking if `hhh` exists, and if so return `hhh` ex:

```
if 'xxx-hhh-111'.include('hhh')
  'hhh'
```

but if I can accomplish both cases with 1 statement, it would be nice...

Comment: [`'xxx-yyy-111'.match /xxx(.*)-111/`](https://repl.it/BXN2/1)

Comment: sorry, had to fix my question... but .match is nice, didnt know about, will research

Comment: [`^xxx(?:(-(?!hhh)[^-]*-[^-]*)|-(hhh)-[^-]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/hA9qT1/1). [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/Dbea3e).

Comment: [match /xxx(-hhh|-yyy-.*)/](https://repl.it/BXN2/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on the capture group : instead of substituting the matched string with another one, you use one of your capture group, delimited by parenthesis, as the result you're looking for.

```
"xxx-hhh-mmm".gsub /xxx-(hhh).*|xxx(.*)/, '\1' #=> 'hhh'
"xxx-yyy-mmm".gsub /xxx-(hhh).*|xxx(.*)/, '\1' #=> '-yyy-mmm'
```

`'\1'` here refers to the pattern match inside the first capture group : either (hhh) or (.*)

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
data = [
  'xxx-hhh-111',
  'xxx-yyy-aaa'
]


data.each do |str|
  p str.sub(/[^-]+(-([^-]+).*)/) {$2=='hhh' ? $2:$1}
end

--output:--
"hhh"
"-yyy-aaa"
```

2)

```
data = [
  'xxx-hhh-111',
  'xxx-yyy-aaa'
]

data.each do |str|
  p str.include?('h') ? 'hhh' : str[3..-1]
end

--output:--
"hhh"
"-yyy-aaa"
```

> but if I can accomplish both cases with 1 statement, it would be nice.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using

```
xxx(-hhh-|-\w{3}-.*).*
```

and replace with first capture group i.e.

```
data.gsub(/xxx(-hhh-|-\w{3}-.*).*/, "\\1")
```

where data are your strings.

Regards

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/xP9aE8/1)

**Edit**: Noticed you don't want the hyphens for `hhh`. Use

```
xxx-?(hhh|-\w{3}-.*).*
```

instead then. [Example here.](https://regex101.com/r/xP9aE8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Let's not overthink this:

```
def extract(str, target)
  middle = str[4,3]
  middle == target ? middle : str[3..-1]
end

extract("cat-hhh-123", "hhh") #=> "hhh" 
extract("cat-dog-123", "hhh") #=> "-dog-123"
```